# CTE never ending execution when specifying a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am facing a wild issue where a Common Table extraction takes very long to finish or apparently its not ending when we have specified a filtering condition in the select clause. 
But it runs fine or finishes in seconds when not specified any conditions

Here is my query

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [Title] ,[WI_ID] ,[TeamName] ,[KeyedInID],WorkItemType ,0 as Level
    FROM tbl_VSTS_AllWorkItems 
    WHERE Parent IS NULL and state<>'Removed'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT t1.[Title] ,t1.[WI_ID] ,t1.[TeamName],t2.[KeyedInID] ,t1.WorkItemType,t2.Level+1
    FROM tbl_VSTS_AllWorkItems t1
    INNER JOIN cte t2
        ON t1.Parent = t2.WI_ID where t1.state<>'Removed'
)
select * from cte
```

So here as you can see I specified the selection without any conditions which execute in 10-25 seconds. But when we have some conditions like

```
select * from cte where [KeyedInID] is not null
```

it taking very long to finish or like a never end process.

But there is strange part as well. I created a table variable and feed that table using same cte like this

```
insert into @myTable
select * from cte
```

then what I did is

```
select * from @myTable where [KeyedinId] is not null
```

It executed everything in just seconds. But the first query without table still executing while Im writing this whole question.

I really really not getting an idea whats going on

Comment: I would have suggested you have a circular reference here, however, considering you don't have `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` in your query then that's less likely (as it would fail after 100 iterations). Perhaps you would be better off showing us some sample data and expected results; as the CTE is clearly not behaviour as you think it is.

Comment: I would be suspicious of a circular reference too, but being that the only change between the two queries is the inclusion of a where predicate, that is clearly not what's happening. Perhaps the execution plan of the two queries might yield something helpful?

Comment: As @Larnu points out, a lack of `maxrecursion 0` suggests that this is simply a really slow query as opposed to an infinite loop.  The OP states that the `cte` *takes very long to finish* but is even longer with a filtering condition.  My vote is that this is either an indexing or table size issue.

Comment: Different queries, different execution plans -- you may want to [include them](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). The optimizer easily goes awry with recursive CTEs because it really doesn't know how many rows will come back, and the estimates it makes are often hilariously wrong. It may think that a specific filter will only yield a handful of rows based on histogram data and choose a nested loop join, for example, when the actual data is quite different, or push the filter to the wrong stage of the execution (CTEs are not materialized first).

Comment: @Larnu I've got confused why its working so smoother when using a table variable and filtering from that table? If a circular referencing issue that could affect at the table insertion as well, isnt it?